# Electron application got launched and disappeared within fraction of second

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am trying the launch the electron based application using chromium. But, once it got launched within fraction of second it got disappeared. Below is my code. How we can keep the application to stay for next action.

And also got below exception in my console. I am using chromium version : 110.0.5481.78
and current chrome browser version: 110.0.5481.77

In electron releases I didnt find the chromium release for Version 110.0.5481.78. [https://github.com/electron/electron/releases]

````
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setBinary("C://folder//folderpath//executableFilePath.exe");            
  options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
 WebDriver weBdriver = new ChromeDriver(options); ```  

Console logs:

   ```  org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 110
        Current browser version is 100.0.4896.143 with binary path C:\Program Files\file\file.exe
        Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
        System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.5'
        Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
            Cr_z_deflate [0x00007FF6EB3BACE2+123234]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB316F82]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB1C772D]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB1F0840]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB1EB5F4]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB1E8F79]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB2251EA]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB21D413]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB1F329E]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB1F454E]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6EB725030+3484560]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6EB76197B+3732699]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6EB765405+3747685]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6EB496EEA+805450]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB323643]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB32BC44]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB32BD74]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF6EB3385FD]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9D6A87034+20]
            RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9D7802651+33]
        
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
            at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
            at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
            at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
            at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
            at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
             ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Its has been resolved now. It happened due to version mismatch. I have installed the latest version of chromium driver. But, our electron application supports the lower version of chromium driver [100.0.4896.143]. We can check this by knowing the electron package which is used by dev team.